# Heroku NodeJS app ("Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app")

Tags: git, node.js, heroku, express

I'm new to NodeJS so please bear with me.

I tried putting my NodeJS app on Heroku but get an error and the push is rejected.

Can anybody help me out here?

---

---

git push heroku master
Counting objects: 397, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (321/321), done.
Writing objects: 100% (397/397), 247.73 KiB | 146.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 397 (delta 52), reused 397 (delta 52)

-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Resolving engine versions

```
   WARNING: No version of Node.js specified in package.json, see:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#versions

   Using Node.js version: 0.10.21
   Using npm version: 1.3.11
```

-----> Fetching Node.js binaries

-----> Vendoring node into slug

-----> Installing dependencies with npm

```
   npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect requires debug@'*' but will load
   npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
   npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
   npm WARN unmet dependency /tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/send requires debug@'*' but will load
   npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
   npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
   npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/node_modules/express/bin/express'
   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
   npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
   npm ERR! or email it to:
   npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

   npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
   npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-MGdc/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-Jn8d/cli.js" "rebuild"
   npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286
   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
   npm ERR! path /tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/node_modules/express/bin/express
   npm ERR! code ENOENT
   npm ERR! errno 34
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/npm-debug.log
   npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

!     Failed to rebuild dependencies with npm

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ '/tmp/node-node-MGdc/bin/node',

1 verbose cli   '/tmp/node-npm-Jn8d/cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'rebuild' ]

2 info using npm@1.3.11

3 info using node@v0.10.21

4 info readInstalled object

5 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286',

5 verbose rebuild   'RUMListSrv@0.0.1' ]

6 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/node_modules/express',

6 verbose rebuild   'express@3.3.7' ]

7 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect',

7 verbose rebuild   'connect@2.8.7' ]

8 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/qs',

8 verbose rebuild   'qs@0.6.5' ]

9 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable',

9 verbose rebuild   'formidable@1.0.14' ]

10 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/cookie-signature',

10 verbose rebuild   'cookie-signature@1.0.1' ]

11 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/buffer-crc32',

11 verbose rebuild   'buffer-crc32@0.2.1' ]

12 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/cookie',

12 verbose rebuild   'cookie@0.1.0' ]

13 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/send',

13 verbose rebuild   'send@0.1.4' ]

14 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node_modules/mime',

14 verbose rebuild   'mime@1.2.11' ]

15 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/fresh',

15 verbose rebuild   'fresh@0.2.0' ]

16 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/range-parser',

16 verbose rebuild   'range-parser@0.0.4' ]

17 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/bytes',

17 verbose rebuild   'bytes@0.2.0' ]

18 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/pause',

18 verbose rebuild   'pause@0.0.1' ]

19 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/uid2',

19 verbose rebuild   'uid2@0.0.2' ]

20 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/methods',

20 verbose rebuild   'methods@0.0.1' ]

21 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/commander',

21 verbose rebuild   'commander@1.2.0' ]

22 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/commander/node_modules/keypress',

22 verbose rebuild   'keypress@0.1.0' ]

23 verbose rebuild path, id [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/mkdirp',

23 verbose rebuild   'mkdirp@0.3.5' ]

24 silly rebuild set [ '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/node_modules/express',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/qs',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/cookie-signature',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/buffer-crc32',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/cookie',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/send',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node_modules/mime',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/fresh',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/range-parser',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/bytes',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/pause',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/uid2',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/methods',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/commander',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/commander/node_modules/keypress',

24 silly rebuild set   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/node_modules/mkdirp' ]

25 info build /tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/node_modules/express

26 info preinstall express@3.3.7

27 verbose linkStuff [ false,

27 verbose linkStuff   false,

27 verbose linkStuff   false,

27 verbose linkStuff   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/node_modules' ]

28 info linkStuff express@3.3.7

29 verbose linkBins express@3.3.7

30 verbose link bins [ { express: './bin/express' },

30 verbose link bins   '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/node_modules/.bin',

30 verbose link bins   false ]

31 verbose linkMans express@3.3.7

32 verbose rebuildBundles express@3.3.7

33 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'buffer-crc32',

33 verbose rebuildBundles   'commander',

33 verbose rebuildBundles   'connect',

33 verbose rebuildBundles   'cookie',

33 verbose rebuildBundles   'cookie-signature',

33 verbose rebuildBundles   'fresh',

33 verbose rebuildBundles   'methods',

33 verbose rebuildBundles   'mkdirp',

33 verbose rebuildBundles   'range-parser',

33 verbose rebuildBundles   'send' ]

34 error Error: ENOENT, chmod '/tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-
1abb04409286/node_modules/express/bin/express'

35 error If you need help, you may report this log at:

35 error     http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues

35 error or email it to:

35 error

36 error System Linux 3.8.11-ec2

37 error command "/tmp/node-node-MGdc/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-Jn8d/cli.js" "rebuild"

38 error cwd /tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286

39 error node -v v0.10.21

40 error npm -v 1.3.11

41 error path /tmp/build_b374fb54-2391-435c-b6f7-1abb04409286/node_modules/express/bin/express

42 error code ENOENT

43 error errno 34

44 verbose exit [ 34, true ]

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

To git@heroku.com:floating-thicket-9559.git

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:floating-thicket-9559.git'

Comment: Can you please also include your package.json contents? i think the error is there.

Comment: Was having the same issue few days ago,
did 
`npm clean cache`

deleted node_modules folder (since mine was pushed to heroku, quite quicker like this)
made 
`npm install`
and after this push was working fine
hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Leg0, that was the problem. added the node_modules to the .gitignore and everything worked fine

Comment: It's `npm cache clean`, not the other way around (`npm clean cache`).